# TCPDF add alt text to image

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is there a way to add an alternative text to an image which is generated with TCPDF?

I've found some docs saying something about this, but after reading about it, it doesn't do it the way it should:

https://rimas-kudelis.github.io/tcpdf/classes/TCPDF.html#method_Image.

If TCPDF does not support it, is there an alternative way to accomplish this?